# Azure application gateway and signalr websockets

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, azure-application-gateway

I have the next setup in azure :

1. One application gateway balancer
2. Two virtual machines in the backend pool of the gateway .
3. On the vms there is a signalr app deployed.

**Problem :**

When a client (browser) will invoke a method on a signalr hub server and the message size is aprox equal or grater then 70kb I receive (enabling logging on signalr client side) :

SignalR: Unclean disconnect from websocket: [no reason given].
SignalR: Closing the Websocket.

SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.

SignalR: [server method] failed to execute. Error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.

Client is disconnected , after it tries to reconnect and send the message again.
On reconnect I get a 101 HTTP response status from the server. Here are the logs:

SignalR: webSockets reconnecting.

SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint

SignalR: Closing the Websocket.

SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection started 
reconnecting before invocation result was received.

SignalR: [server method] failed to execute. Error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.
SignalR: webSockets reconnecting.

SignalR: Websocket opened.

**Question :**
Does Azure Application Gateway has some limitations for the websockets message size ?

I tried this on a vm in Azure , by directly accessing IIS and I don't get the same error for the same message when I try to send it from the client to signalr hub .

I couldn't find any reference in azure application gateway documentation about max size for websockets messages.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SignalR has a default limit of 64KB for websocket messages. You can modify it by setting the [MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Configuration/IConfigurationManager.cs#L46-L51)

Comment: Cheers ! Works ok now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignalR has a default limit of 64KB for websocket messages. You can change (or remove) the limit by setting [IConfigurationManager.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Configuration/IConfigurationManager.cs#L46-L51)